# Tuning @JmsListener

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

Does @JmsListener use a poller under the hood, or is it message-driven? When testing with concurrency=1, it seems to read one message per second:

```
2016-06-23 09:09:46.117  INFO 13044 --- [enerContainer-1] c.s.s.core.service.PolicyChangedHandler  : Received: 1: This is a test
2016-06-23 09:09:46.922  INFO 13044 --- [enerContainer-1] c.s.s.core.service.PolicyChangedHandler  : Received: 2: This is a test
2016-06-23 09:09:47.730  INFO 13044 --- [enerContainer-1] c.s.s.core.service.PolicyChangedHandler  : Received: 3: This is a test
2016-06-23 09:09:48.535  INFO 13044 --- [enerContainer-1] c.s.s.core.service.PolicyChangedHandler  : Received: 4: This is a test
2016-06-23 09:09:49.338  INFO 13044 --- [enerContainer-1] c.s.s.core.service.PolicyChangedHandler  : Received: 5: This is a test
2016-06-23 09:09:50.155  INFO 13044 --- [enerContainer-1] c.s.s.core.service.PolicyChangedHandler  : Received: 6: This is a test
```

If it is polling, how do I adjust the polling rate or increase the number of messages read per poll?

If it is message-driven, I don't why it is so slow???

Answer (score 0):

Yes Spring JMSListener uses polling under the hood by default. 
See [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html)
See also  the [default receiveTimeout](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.html#DEFAULT_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT) which is 1s.

*The receive timeout for each attempt can be configured through the "receiveTimeout" property.* [setReceiveTimeout](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.html#setReceiveTimeout-long-)
Set the timeout to use for receive calls, in milliseconds. The default is 1000 ms, that is, 1 second.

*NOTE: This value needs to be smaller than the transaction timeout used by the transaction manager (in the appropriate unit, of course). 0 indicates no timeout at all; however, this is only feasible if not running within a transaction manager and generally discouraged since such a listener container cannot cleanly shut down. A negative value such as -1 indicates a no-wait receive operation.*